# Internal IP of amazon Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services

Is there any way to find out the internal IP of my ELB. I realise it's dynamic and changes every so often but I'm looking into a large number of packets flooding the server and all I have to go on is an internal Amazon IP

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `netstat`, `tcpdump` or looking in the logs?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no indication of what happened during the time it was connected, just that it was connected.

Comment: So this happened in the past and isn't happening any more?  So what you want to find out is what IP your ELB had at some point in the past.  Is that correct?  Put a sample of whatever logs you *do* have in your question.

Comment: This happened about half an hour ago. but after following your suggestion of netstat, I then tried browsing to the IP in lynx, sure enough it redirected me to my website. Now I just have to work out why the ELB was sending so much data all of a sudden. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ELB ip address is the ip address that connects to your instances.  The source client IP address is found in the request's X-Forwarded-For header.